# Upgrading to Vue 3: [Vue warn]: Computed property "actions" is already defined in Props

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I'm currently migration a Vue 2 application to Vue 3, and for some reason I'm suddenly getting this warning a lot:

`[Vue warn]: Computed property "actions" is already defined in Props.`

This happens in a bunch of different components, with a bunch of different properties. If I use the Vue devtools to inspect some components, it looks that a lot of components suddenly have computed properties that are not part of that component, but rather are defined on the parent or grandparent. Somehow all computed properties are passed to child components automatically.

I have no idea what's causing this, and I can't find anything about it in the docs. Also it seems that the warning doesn't always trigger (for example after refreshing they might be gone), so I'm thinking if it's some sort of weird bug.

Btw it doesn't seem to break anything so far.

Thanks in advance!

(Ps. I'm using Vite)

Comment: Do you have a setup function? are you not using componentAPI or just Options API?  Might be a Vuex issue too.

Comment: Can you share some of the code, like one of the components that has this issue? It sounds like a conflict with one of the libraries you're using.

Comment: You could start with checking places where `action` word occurs besides a store.

Comment: Sorry, as I mentioned in the answer I just posted it was very random so I didn't know which code to share. But I've found that it's caused by Vue devtools (somehow), and is not related to the actual code

Answer (score 8):

The reason I didn't include any code in my question was because the warning seemed to trigger on many different places / components, and also it seemed to not always trigger, so it was hard to find out what the relevant code was.

I've found that it's an issue with Vue devtools however. When I disable the devtools, I'm not getting the warning. Also noticed that the devtools was slowing down rendering time, not sure if that's related to this issue.

Comment: I have this same issue.  For me it goes away if I disable and re-enable the Vue Devtools extension.